# C taking in arguments from Command prompt as conditions

Tags: c, multithreading, argv, argc

I'm completely new to C...well sort of. i kind know c++. I'm trying to run a multi-threated program for my assignment, and one of the requirements was to have the user input his commands on the command prompt. 
Essentially what i'm asking is, how can i set up int main so that it can constantly take inputs from the command prompt(so i can start new threads) without stopping, and how to make comparisons such as  if the user presses 'E' do this, if he presses F do that and so on. 
I'm guessing that the argc doesnt matter at all because i don't know how many commands the user is going to enter. What would be the best way to go on about this

Comment: say, the user presses e twice(then create 2 threads). He inputs S to stop all the threads running and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-Interface-Thread:

```
void *trd_func(void *p) {
  while (1) {
    int c = getchar();
    switch(c) {
        case 'E':
             set_some_flag('E');
             break;
        default: break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: would i need to call this everytime the user inputs something on the command prompt?

Comment: you need to dedicate a thread to do this. then you can forget about it, the thread will continuously read and process input.

Comment: sorry but why do I have to start a new thread though, This is my main thread and it's going to be the one that controls the creation of other threads, their running and so on. isn't there a way to keep this on this main thread?

Comment: i see that the benefits of this is that i will always have this running like you said, and i won't have to worry about it, but can i combine the two and always be checking for input or not really? sorry for so many questions but i'm just trying to grasp this better

Comment: you can have this on the main thread of course. It is also a thread and you can dedicate it to this purpose, which makes more sense really.

Answer (score 2):

When a program is started, command line arguments are passed to `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and these do not change (unless the program modifies them).

After that, the program can read from standard input to get commands such as `E` for 'do this' and `F` for 'do that'.  Unless you take platform-specific steps to make it behave otherwise, the input will not be provided to your program until the user hits return after typing the command.

So, you can process command line arguments if they're provided.  Once you've done that, you might go interactive and wait for more input from the user.

Multithreading has very little to do with this.  You'll probably need a single thread to read from the user (otherwise, someone or something will get confused), but communication between the threads is otherwise a wholly separate problem.

Comment: ok.that makes sense. so i can just have a int c = getchar() like @perreal said with a switch statement that will be constantly taking in values without me having to ask for them?

Answer (score 2):

Have the master thread in charge of i/o.

- Print a prompt to the user for input from the master thread.
- Pass the user input from the master thread to the worker threads.
- Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really learn by doing what you want to do,

you should start looking for information about file streams, and about ttys/canonical input.

And when you'll have understood how this works, you'll be able to use the read() function, and do whatever you want to interact with the user (even do a shell).

I can guarantee you that you will have learned many interesting things about I/O file streams.

But as mentioned before, you can also use getchar().